# Retrieve saved value and bind it to ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I bind users' input with ng-model in the view like this

```
<input ng-model="car">
```

and in my controller I have $scope.car to get the value and store it somewhere. In my case I store it into localstorage, but how to get the saved value from localstorage and set it to $scope.car?

I tried

```
    var settingFrmStorage = $localstorage.getObject('vehicles');

    $scope.car = settingFrmStorage[0].type.car;
```

but I don't see any value in my input. I `console.log(settingFrmStorage[0].type.car;)` I can see the value is there.

Comment: can you please you json object?

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues which could cause that.

1. You're doing it outside of a digest cycle. Therefore the angular framework doesn't detect the change and doesn't update the element.
2. You get run into scoping troubles because you use a flat reference. See [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) for details

So, to make it short: 
Use an object as data store.

```
$scope.carStore.car = 'some value';
```

In your markup:

```
<input ng-model="carStore.car">
```

If that doesn't work, it means you have to trigger $apply yourself.